# How can i change the style of the drop down panel of a select box to have round corners for chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome-extension, webkit

Hi I am having an angular 5, application . I have a select box with some a list of options .I want to give round corners for the panel that displays the options in chrome . How can I achieve this with css styles ?

Please see the attachment below.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the border-radius setting.

F.i.:

```
#rcorners1 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: #73AD21;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
}

#rcorners2 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
}

#rcorners3 {
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: url(paper.gif);
  background-position: left top;
  background-repeat: repeat;
  padding: 20px; 
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px; 
}
```